# Sometime facebook authorization redirects to browse/admined_pages

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, authorization

I have an application that connects user pages to manage posts etc. and sometimes after last step instead of closing popup it just redirects to facebook.com/browse/admined_pages and doesn't allow to proceed. This happenes only for some users. Most of them have buisness pages, but not all business pages have the same issue

I expect the popup to redirect to my app, where I will add info and close